# $n = 2^k + 1$ is a prime iff $3^{\frac{n-1}{2}} \equiv -1 \pmod n$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

Let $k \geq 2$ be a positive integer and let $n=2^k+1$. How can I prove that $n$ is a prime number if and only if
$$3^{\frac{n-1}{2}} \equiv -1 \pmod n.$$

*Fixed.*

Comment: This is not true in general (consider $k=1$ for example). You need some additional conditions. Look at Proth's theorem. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proth%27s_theorem

Comment: Note that one needs to ask that $k \ge 2$.

Comment: The title of the question is misleading.

Comment: @lhf: I changed the title as I agree the title was misleading. One could maybe add $k \geq 2$ to the title as well, but I'm not sure if the title doesn't become too long then.

Comment: The easier half of this proposition is established for [this newer Question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1815066/prove-that-3q-1-2-equiv-1-pmod-q-then-q-is-prime-number).  Since neither implication is really detailed here, I don't see treating either of these Questions as a duplicate.

Answer (score 7):

Here are two options for finding a proper proof for this theorem (called Pepin's test).

1) [http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pepin's_test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pepin%27s_test).

2) "Solved and Unsolved Problems in Number Theory" by Daniel Shanks.
This book includes the proof for that theorem.

Answer (score 5):

This is the simplest case of Pratt certificates for primality - have a look at http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PrattCertificate.html for a better explanation. (In the notation of the article, your question corresponds to the case where the only $p_i$ is $2$.)