# Prove that $3^{(q-1)/2} \equiv -1 \pmod q$ then q is prime number.

Tags: prime-numbers, modules, divisibility

$q=2^m+1, m\ge 2$. Prove that if $$3^{(q-1)/2} \equiv -1 \pmod q$$ then q is prime number.

I want to use if $q-1 | \phi(q)$, then q is prime number.  But I don't know how to transform above equation.

So how should I start?

Comment: This is essentially half (one-sided implication) of [Pépin's test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P%C3%A9pin%27s_test) for primality of Fermat numbers.  The converse says that if $q=2^m+1$ is prime, then the congruence shown in the Question holds.  (It must further be true that if $q$ is prime, exponent $m$ is a power of two.)

Comment: I went ahead and replaced $p$ in the next to last sentence (it is mentioned nowhere else in your Question) by $q$, which you will note makes perfect sense given the Accepted Answer.  Please review and rollback the edits if they do not match your intended meaning.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have the right idea. Note that $\gcd(3,q)=1$, by Euler's theorem $3^{\phi(q)}\equiv 1(\mod q)$, and hence the order of $3$ module $q$ is a divisor of $\phi(q)$. Hence, if we can prove $q-1$ is the order of $3$ modulo $q$, you can use the statement you mentioned.

Now, assume $h=$ the order of $3$ modulo $q$. Since $3^{\frac{q-1}{2}}\equiv -1(\mod q)$, we have $3^{q-1}\equiv 1(\mod q)\Rightarrow h|(q-1)\Rightarrow h|2^m$. However, $3^{\frac{q-1}{2}}\equiv -1\neq 1(\mod q)$, thus $h\nmid 2^{m-1}\Rightarrow h=2^m=q-1$.

Comment: But how can I use this statement $3^{(q−1)/2}≡−1(mod q)$?

Comment: Ahh from that 3^(q−1)/2≡−1(mod q) we have that 3^(q-1) ≡ 1 mod q so q-1 | phi (q) and we prove it

Comment: That's correct!